# Email server: Remove rua from DMARC DNS entry or stop receiving DMARC reports

Tags: email, email-server, dmarc

I have the following DNS entry for one of my clients email servers:

```
_dmarc IN TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@example.com"
```

This is the only email server I'm administering, which has a DMARC DNS entry - in other cases SPF and DKIM was always sufficient for the email server to work fine.

The annoying thing is that I receive multiple DMARC reports from Gmail, Yahoo, etc. ervery day and I don't need them. How can I stop receiving those DMARC reports?

Should I just remove the `rua` part of the DNS entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Just remove it. "rua" is optional as per RFC.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489

Comment: Could you be please so kind and show me the part where it is exactly? I can't find the part which says, that "rua" is optional. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Page 19.  rua:  Addresses to which aggregate feedback is to be sent (comma-separated plain-text list of DMARC URIs; OPTIONAL)

Answer (score 0):

yes you should remove the rua=mailto:postmaster@example.com it's optional